# This overload of the method 'System.Linq.Queryable.TakeLast' is currently not supported

Tags: linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an ASP .Net Core 2.2 Web API using Entity Framework Core.
It connects to a MySQL database using the latest version of Pomelo.
When I try to execute the Linq function "TakeLast", like this:

```
var messages = dbContext.Messages
                   .TakeLast(5)
                   .ToList();
```

I get this error:

Exception thrown: 'System.NotSupportedException' in Remotion.Linq.dll

System.NotSupportedException: Could not parse expression 'value(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[PropWorx.API.Models.Message]).TakeLast(__p_0)': This overload of the method 'System.Linq.Queryable.TakeLast' is currently not supported.

The Ling function "Take" works - but "TakeLast" doesn't. Is this a limitation of MySql? Or Pomelo? Any workaround?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each provider is responsible for implementing the LINQ expression translation that works for their particular platform. It would appear, yes, that Pomelo has not provided support for `TakeLast`.

As far as workarounds go, two things. First you should never use `Skip`/`Take` without an order by clause. The default order is going to be primary key, but depending on the type of the key, that could end up almost being entirely random. It's always better to be explicit about the ordering, so you understand *exactly* what's being taken from the results.

Second, assuming you have an ordering, to get `TakeLast` functionality, you simply need to reverse the ordering and use `Take` instead. For example, lets assume you're pulling messages by creation date:

```
var messages = dbContext.Messages.OrderBy(o => o.Created).TakeLast(5).ToList();
```

What you're really saying here is that you want the ones with the latest created date, so you could do instead:

```
var messages = dbContext.Messages.OrderByDescending(o => o.Created).Take(5).ToList();
```

To achieve the same result.

Comment: Perfect! Much better than some enumerable implementations  was seeing with circular buffers and crazy stuff like that.

Comment: What are the performance implications here in terms of very large result sets, say, 80 million? I never have a clear overview of that.

Comment: Pulling 80 million records at once isn't ever going to be performant, no matter what. However, if the column(s) you order by are indexed, performance will be as good as it can be.